# Ubuntu 15.04 Client doesn't create xrdp desktop?

Tags: server, 15.04, rdp, xrdp, client

We've been having a bit of an issue, and saying that it's a *bit* of an issue is an understatement. Our client (Ubuntu 15.04, specs linked) has these installed, and in this order:

1. Ubuntu-desktop (already installed, but we did sudo apt-get install and found out)
2. TightVNCServer
3. XRDP (with, of course vnc4server installed with the package)

When we connect from mstsc on Windows, it successfully connects to the server, and xrdp does its little "Connection log" on the left hand side. Once it's done, it gives us a checkered background, and then disconnects. What I, personally, can't figure out is why after editing .xsession in the remote user's directory with this:
`gnome-session --session=Ubuntu-2d`, it just closes the connection without giving us a session to work in. And every time it does, it leaves an iteration in the log file ".xsession-errors" (also attached). Anyone have any clues as to why this may be? We'd really appreciate any assistance you can give!

http://pastebin.com/N7DBqjxg

http://pastebin.com/KjJpaRTw

Comment: encountered same problem

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a bug with xrdp 0.6.1-2 doesn't work via sesman-X11rdp. See bug report [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xrdp/+bug/220005). At the time of this answer the bug was not fixed, but there is a possible [workaround here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xrdp/+bug/220005/comments/20).

There are many workarounds others have posted to this site.I hope this helps! Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue.  When installing xrdp, you will need to specify an alternate desktop to be used while using xrdp.  Unity or Gnome 3 are not working with XRDP and UBuntu 12.10 and later.

You have modified you .xsession file and add the command `gnome-session --session=Ubuntu-2d`.   There is no more ubuntu-2d in Ubuntu since 12.10.

So to have things working, you have to perform the following steps:

1. install xrdp
2. install alternate desktop (let say you choose mate-desktop)
3. update the .xsession and add mate-session in the file
4. try to connect and you should be good to go

You can find detailed instruction [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=7984). The blog provides also more information about xrdp (how to install different desktop; how to have vnc running at startup...)